# Return initial letters of postcode in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the initial letters from a postcode in javascript? I just want the letters before the numbers start, like this:

```
E.g - 'L159XU' would return 'L'
E.g - 'TW136PZ' would return 'TW'
```

I was originally doing this:

```
const letters = postcode.substring(0, 2);
```

But some only have one letter, while others have two. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Hint: `^[A-Z]+` should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this:
HTML

```
<p id="test"></p>
```

JavaScript Regular Expressions

```
let text = 'TW136PZ';
let pattern = /[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+/g;
let result = text.match(pattern);

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result[0]; // return "TW"
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `split` function with a regex,

```js
let res = "TW136PZ".split(/[0-9]+/)[0] ; // TW
```

more about [regex here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

```js
   

const postc='TwA1234';

const letters=postc.match( /^[a-zA-Z]+/ )[0];

console.log(letters);
```

`^` – begin of input

`a-z` – lowercase English Letters included

`A-Z` – Uppercases included

`+` – one or more times it appears!

As you wanted, it returns a string of as many initial latin latters as needed, three in this case.

Comment: Note: `match` returns a list, OP needs to get the first element (`[0]`)

Answer (score 0):

There are different valid implementations

```js
function callX() {
    return 'TW136PZ'.slice(0, 'TW136PZ'.search(/[0-9]/))
}
function callY() {
    return 'TW136PZ'.split(/[0-9]+/)[0]
}
function callZ() {
    return 'TW136PZ'.match( /^[a-zA-Z]+/ )[0]
}
```

when benchmarking these:

```js
performance.mark("beginX");
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    callX();
}
performance.mark("endX");

performance.mark("beginY");
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    callY();
}
performance.mark("endY");

performance.mark("beginZ");
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    callZ();
}
performance.mark("endZ");

performance.measure("X","beginX","endX");
performance.measure("Y","beginY","endY");
performance.measure("Z","beginZ","endZ");

console.log(performance.getEntriesByType("measure"))
```

it turns out the first implementation is the fastest, while the second implementation (using `split`) is the slowest.
I think this is due to not requiring to instantiate another array.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a solution that does not use regular expressions, because I haven't seen one:

```js
function parsePostcode(postcode) {
    const charIsADigit = function(ch) {
        const code = ch.charCodeAt(0)

        return code >= 48 && 58 > code;
    };

    let prefix = ""

    for (let i = 0; i < postcode.length; ++i) {
        const ch = postcode[i]
        const is_digit = charIsADigit(ch)

        if (is_digit) break;

        prefix += ch
    }

    return prefix;
}

console.log(parsePostcode("L159XU"))
console.log(parsePostcode("TW136PZ"))
```